# Multiprocessing handling return values and passing into next function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Right, my head hurts... 
I am trying to get the number of pdfs in a directory and then read each file and convert into a few excel files. I got this working already without multiprocessing but it is slow.

```
def main():
    pdfFiles = get_PDFs()
    for onePDF in pdfFiles:

        # Reads the pdf, this is intensive. Returns a to i, most of which are lists
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = start_up_converter(onePDF) 

        # preprocessing
        j, k = process_df(c)  # j is a dataframe, k is a list
        l = merge_orders(j)

        # populate and build the excel file 1
        build_file(l, b, i, f, e, d, g, k) # uses values from above funcs

        # before building excel 2 and 3, more preprocessing
        m, n = process_df2(c, d, g)

        # populate and build the excel file 2 and 3
        build_form('records', m, d, n)
        build_form('data', m, d, n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

As you can see, this is a simple program, with values got from 1 function passed into another. Because the number of pdf files is large, it makes sense for me to drop the loop and go with multiprocessing. But examples out there do not really handle returned values, and passing these values into the next function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def main(onePDF):
    # Reads the pdf, this is intensive. Returns a to i, most of which are lists
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = start_up_converter(onePDF) 

    # preprocessing
    j, k = process_df(c)  # j is a dataframe, k is a list
    l = merge_orders(j)

    # populate and build the excel file 1
    build_file(l, b, i, f, e, d, g, k) # uses values from above funcs

    # before building excel 2 and 3, more preprocessing
    m, n = process_df2(c, d, g)

    # populate and build the excel file 2 and 3
    build_form('records', m, d, n)
    build_form('data', m, d, n)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdfFiles = get_PDFs()
    pool = Pool(processes=12)
    a = pool.map(main, pdfFiles)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```